# Is this question really too broad and not simply off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration, close-reasons

[Why would computers transfer data and instructions form main memory to cache in blocks when this means a single cache miss may overwrite a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446371/why-would-computers-transfer-data-and-instructions-form-main-memory-to-cache-in) was put on hold as too broad. While I can see it is off-topic for StackOverflow, I *suspect* it is not too broad and migration (say to the [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)) might be reasonable.

I *think* [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22467116) is more-or-less complete (addressing the "too many answers" issue) and not *extremely* long (a little over 3300 characters).

The question is not a great question even for the CS SE, but it is question that seems to be generally answered with a simple "larger cache blocks exploit the spatial locality that is typical in most programs" and a somewhat broader answer seems likely to be helpful.

(Knowing that the question was off-topic on StackOverflow, I should not have given an answer [encouraging off-topic posts is wrong] and perhaps flagged the question for migration. I am not sure if CS SE would accept this question, but CS SE does handle a fair number of similarly simple computer architecture questions.)

Comment: Does the OP really mean "instructions form" or do they mean "instructions from"?

Comment: @RobertHarvey First "on hold" replaced "closed" (for a period of time) to encourage fixing questions. Second, my point is I do not think it qualifies as "too broad" ("off-topic", yes, but not "too broad").

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yes, the OP meant "from" not "form".

Comment: Good to know, I don't know enough about the topic to know if that means something specific in the context of the OP's question.